# Unable to declare Interface " async Task<myObject> MyMethod(Object myObj); "

Tags: c#, async-await, interface, asp.net-4.5

I'm unable to declare

```
interface IMyInterface
{
   async Task<myObject> MyMethod(Object myObj);
}
```

The compiler tells me:

- The modifier async isn't valid for this item
- The async modifier can only be used for methods that have a body

Is this something that should be implemented, or does the nature of async & await prohibit this from ever occurring?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> Whether a method is implemented using `async`/`await` or not is an
> *implementation* detail. How the method should *behave* is a contract
> detail, which should be specified in the normal way.
>
> Note that if you make the method return a `Task` or a `Task<T>`, it's more
> obvious that it's meant to be asynchronous, and will probably be hard
> to implement without being asynchronous.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274601/4384

Comment: This could get ugly. Async method name usually should end with an `Async` suffix. Not able to enforce async implementation for a method defined in a interface (with `Async` in the name) means that we could have a non-async methods with Async suffix in their names. Or if we chose not to do so, we would have async methods without async suffix in their names. Is there a convention that people follow?

Comment: Yes it is just convention, and like all conventions some people choose their own way. However as in the quote above, returning a `Task` / `Task<T>` vs `void` / `T` does make it more obvious, and harder to implement incorrectly.

Comment: @GiriB - whether a method is implemented with or without `async` is of no concern to the caller. You can be asynchronous without , and synchroinous with that keyword.

Answer (score 22):

Whether or not your implementation is async, has no relevance to your interface. In other words, the interface cannot specify that a given method must be implemented in an asynchronous way.

Just take `async` out of your interface and it will compile; however, there is no way to enforce asynchronous implementation just by specifying an interface.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an interface with two implementations (one that is truly async and the other that is synchronous) this is what it would look like for each implementation - with both returning a `Task<bool>`.

```
public interface IUserManager
{
    Task<bool> IsUserInRole(string roleName);
}

public class UserManager1 : IUserManager
{
    public async Task<bool> IsUserInRole(string roleName)
    {
        return await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(_profile.Id, roleName);
    }
}

public class UserManager2 : IUserManager
{
    public Task<bool> IsUserInRole(string roleName)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Roles.IsUserInRole(roleName));
    }
}
```

If it is a void method you need to `return Task.CompletedTask;` from the non async method 
(I think .NET 4.5 and later)

See also : [Return Task<bool> instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846507/return-taskbool-instantly)

Answer (score 1):

The `async` modifier is an 'implementation detail', it affects *how* a method can do stuff asynchronously, not *if* it does so.

So `async` has no business being inside an interface.

```
interface IService { Task DoSomethingAsync(); }

class A : IService { public async Task DoSomethingAsync() { ... } }

class B : IService { public Task DoSomethingAsync() { ... } }
```

Classes A and B are both perfectly valid. Both methods are awaitable. A consumer of the interface doesn't know or care if they use `async`.

`B.DoSomethingAsync()` can be and probably will be asynchronous.