# Return Task<bool> instantly

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, task-parallel-library

I have a list of tasks, which i'd like to wait for. I'm waiting like

```
    await TaskEx.WhenAll(MyViewModel.GetListOfTasks().ToArray());
```

MyViewModel.GetListOfTasks() returns List of Task:

```
    var tasksList = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var item in Items)
    {                
        tasksList.Add(item.MyTask());
    }
```

Now, i'd like to return dummy task, which would be done immediately. However, TaskEx.WhenAll would wait it forever:

```
    public Task<bool> MyTask()
    {
        return new Task<bool>(() => false);
    }
```

How can i return Task, which would be finished instantly?

Comment: Should you be mocking this out with a different service layer?

Comment: @DavidL Yep, that's what i'm going to do, but at the current moment i'm just playing with new architecture, so i'd like to first fill it with dummies, and then starting working on implementation.

Comment: return Task.FromResult(false);

Comment: @FabioMarcolini Thanks, that works! For wp7, it would be return TaskEx.FromResult(false); but you're rignt.

Comment: You're creating a Task, but you never run it.

Comment: @user2674389 why not? If to put there task with await, it works fine.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

in .NET 4.5 you can use FromResult to immediately return a result for your task.

```
public Task<bool> MyTask()
{
    return TaskEx.FromResult(false);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228607%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

---

For Windows Phone 8.1 and higher, the [API has been merged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx) to be consistent with other platforms:

```
public Task<bool> MyTask()
{
    return Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

Comment: Since the final release of the Framework its: return Task.FromResult(false);

Comment: @uli78 this question was specifically for windows phone 7, but great point!  I've updated my answer, thank you!

Comment: In case it is in this form, you should add await: public async Task<bool> MyTask()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(false);
}

Comment: @Anand-MCSAMCPDMCTSMCSD in the OP's (and your) example, there is no reason to generate an additional state machine to await.

Answer (score 11):

Prior to .NET 4.5, you can use [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) to simulate the `FromResult` method.

```
public static Task<TResult> FromResult<TResult>(TResult result)
{
    var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
    completionSource.SetResult(result);
    return completionSource.Task;
}
```

Comment: But why would i want to simulate it? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Because prior to .NET 4.5, there is no `FromResult` method.

Comment: But.. well.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx - i guess, it is?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko You are looking at 4.5, [go up a level and change the .net version to 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task_methods%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and you will see `FromResult` is not an available method.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But we are talking about 4.5?

Comment: @280Z28 Well, anyway, thanks for your answer - its always good to keep analogues in mind, and to know what's inside.