# No warning when I forget `await` on an interface method call

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.FooAsync(); // warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
        ((I)c).FooAsync(); // No warning
    }
}

class C : I
{
    public async Task FooAsync()
    {
    }
}

interface I
{
    Task FooAsync();
}
```

If I call the async method directly on the `c` object, I get a compiler warning. There's potentially a bug here, so I'm glad for the warning.

However, if I make the same call on an interface method, I get no warning. It would be easy to let a bug slip past in this code.

How can I ensure that I don't make this mistake? Is there a pattern I can apply to protect myself?

Comment: Good question... Since one can't mark interface methods async I don't expect compiler to give you warning in this case. Maybe someone knows if R# does so (or there is plugin for it).

Comment: ReSharper does not catch it.

Comment: It's possible [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) could find it with a custom "CQL" query run during the build process - but since `async` is a compiler trick and is not actually compiled into the IL, I doubt it.

Comment: crazy enough, you could also have an interface member like `void Foo()` and then implement it in your class with `void async Foo()`. No warning, but drastically unexpected behavior

Comment: I suppose you could write a simple code parser that looks at your codefiles for a regex representing `{something}.{something}Async` or maybe just `{something}Async` and ensures that it's preceded by `await `. Then as long as your naming conventions are consistent, you could make that part of your build process.

Comment: I think a Roslyn analyzer will be your best bet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254643/find-missing-await-in-solution. one of these days, one of us should really write one ...

Comment: The `Lindhart.Analyser.MissingAwaitWarning` Nuget does the job perfectly

Answer (score 7):

Main is not async, so it can't use `await`. This seems to confuse the compiler messages slightly. If you put the calls into an actual async method;

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
                       {
                           C c = new C();
                           c.FooAsync();
                           ((I) c).FooAsync();
                       });
}
```

...both will warn.

> Line 10: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
>   Line 11: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

EDIT: It seems like all methods that return `Task` *inside async methods* will warn unless you await or assign them; note that we're working with the interface that doesn't even mention async;

```
interface I
{
    Task FooAsync();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    I i = null;

    i.FooAsync();             // Does not warn
    // await i.FooAsync();    // Can't await in a non async method
    var t1 = i.FooAsync();    // Does not warn

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
       i.FooAsync();          // Warns CS4014
       await i.FooAsync();    // Does not warn
       var t2 = i.FooAsync(); // Does not warn
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The logic for this warning seems to be:

- in an `async` method, warn whenever a `Task`-returning method is called, but the result is ignored
- in a normal (non-`async`) method, warn whenever a `Task`-returning `async` method is called, but the result is ignored

For example, look at this (nonsensical) code:

```
Task NonAsyncMethod()
{
    AsyncMethod(); // warnig
    NonAsyncMethod(); // no warning

    return null; // to make the code compile
}

async Task AsyncMethod()
{
    AsyncMethod(); // warning
    NonAsyncMethod(); // warning
}
```

This is why you're not getting the warning with the interface: the interface method isn't (and can't) be marked as `async`.

I think the reason for this is that in old, pre-`async` code, it's common to for example call `task.ContinueWith()` and ignore its result. If the warning was reported in this case too, relatively large amount of old correct code would suddenly become warnings.

A warning should be output when there is a large likelihood of a bug. I think that the cases that are reported are much more likely to be bugs than the case which isn't. So to me, this behavior make sense.

If you want to make sure you don't make this mistake, be careful about calling `Task`-returning methods from non-`async` code.

Comment: "be careful about...". Grumble, I hate being careful.

Answer (score 2):

The `Lindhart.Analyser.MissingAwaitWarning` NuGet package checks this for you. Install the nuget package in your projects and you'll get a compiler warning when a method returns a Task that is not awaited.

[more info](https://github.com/ykoksen/unused-task-warning)

Answer (score 1):

I would venture to say that it is impossible to make this warning on compilation level. to support my point, look at this example:

```
interface I
{
    Task Foo();
}

class A : I
{
    public Task Foo()
    {
    }
}

class B : I
{
    public async Task Foo()
    {
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        I i;

        if (Console.ReadLine() == "1")
        {
            i = new A();
        }
        else i = new B();

        i.Foo();
    }
}
```

Your first thought might be: But this is an absurd situation. But some design patterns (an example is the factory method) using mechanisms instantiate derived classes from a very dynamic way.

So how the VS can know if the method is async or not?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may be asking for too much here.

```
interface I
{
    void Foo();
}

class C {} // does not implement I

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C c = new C();
        ((I)c).Foo(); // Generates no compiler warning
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, casting happens at runtime and there is nothing such as `async` at runtime (or in CIL). Compiler converts `async Task Foo()` into `Task Foo()` implemented as a `state-machine` of co-routines.