# Find missing await in solution

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, roslyn-code-analysis

I have lots of async methods in my server code, but I suspect that I have callers without await.

Is there a simple way to scan the code for calls where await is missing?

```
public async Task DomeSomethingAsync() 
{
     var result = await GetResult();
     await StoreResult(result);
}
```

then somewhere I've forgot to use await;

```
public async Task SomeBuggyCode()
{
     await Initialize();
     DoSomethingAsync();  // DOH - Forgot await
}
```

I was hoping there was a smart way to identitfy these erroronous calls.

Comment: @Frode: is Roslyn required specifically? or any reasonable way of finding them is OK? If you don't need Roslyn, please remove that from the question, that will make clear that answers like from Charles are good

Comment: Good to know. When using resharper for a long time, you start to mess up what is done by it and what is not :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be shown as compiler warning CS4014 with the text:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873131.aspx)

So all you should need to do is compile the code.  VS should allow you to navigate to the relevant locations from its Error List.

Comment: This is obviously the best way. The reason I didn't get this warning was because I had functions that returned Task but were not async. I just returned Task.CompletedTask for some reason. Made them async now.

Comment: Marking a method "async" tells the compiler that the method implementation is asynchronous, and that await is permitted within.  The "async" characteristic is not visible from outside the method, the best way to tell if a method is asynchronous is when the method returns a Task.  If your project contains the async method and also the caller, then the compiler can warn you.  But if the async method is in some other assembly (even the BCL), the compiler may not be able to warn you.  So this answer is mostly right, but might be wrong for cases where the async method is in an external assembly.

Answer (score 9):

The CS4014 warning will get generated if the missing "await" is to a method that the compiler knows is async.

It won't work if you miss an await when calling an async method via an interface or in an external library.

For that reason, it's worth installing this nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lindhart.Analyser.MissingAwaitWarning/

this will raise a warning in any cases where a method that returns a Task is not awaited

Comment: This is a awsome packge and show all methods where await is missing and those are not picked by built in build command. many many thanks

Comment: There is no other answer currently. VS + Lindhart is the combination to trap all these await missing

Answer (score 5):

A special case. The answer is only for the Rider IDE by JetBrains.
You can use InspectCode, and find all calls async method without await:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to find them all is just compile the code.

Any function that has async but no await inside of it will cause [compiler warning CS4014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873131.aspx), once you compile your project look through the list of warnings and you will see all of the functions you need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

If the method doesn't contains even one await you may check the output window. After compilation you'll find `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously ...` warning. Double click on that warning will take you to the relevant method.

Answer (score 1):

True you'll get the warning BUT if your app works without waiting those functions maybe you don't want to await them, just assign the resulting task to a variable to turn off the warning the guys told you about.

Obviously this is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that the warnings above can still miss where an await is missing, such as this line:

`var before = _repositoryBase.GetAsync(id).CloneJson();`

If you have a naming convention that all async methods are called XXXAsync the following regex will help find potentional missing awaits:

`^((?!(await|async)).)*Async\(`

[Missing async await text search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqzAy.png)

Comment: I like the regex but it does not work for the multi line statements.