# How to avoid the error "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" in EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, .net-6.0

I just got the error "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" in my ASP.NET Core application and found out that I was running two queries in parallel by mistake. However, now I am not sure how exactly I have to take care of avoiding DbContext threading issues. On [Avoiding DbContext threading issues](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=2097913) it is mentioned that I should not perform any parallel operations on the same DbContext instance, but when exactly am I even working with the same DbContext instance in my application?

I call `services.AddDbContext()` in my `ConfigureServices()` method in the Startup.cs file and then inject the context via the constructor in my data accessor classes where I then use it to perform queries against the database. Therefore, as I am not manually creating any instances of the context myself, I do not fully understand when and how the context is instantiated.

What happens if, for example, two users click on the same button in my frontend which initiates the same request to my backend and therefore the same query is called at the same time (assuming both users really performed the operation at the exact same time)? Is the same DbContext instance used in both cases, or do both requests each have their own DbContext instance?

Comment: Probably you have missed `await` or introduced `async void` method.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Maybe it's not that clear in my question, but I already solved my problem. My question is more related to this error in general and how I can avoid running into it again. It's not about fixing the problem where I first got this error in my project.

Comment: Probably [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254643/find-missing-await-in-solution) may help

Comment: Each request will be given a single DbContext instance, so two or more users hitting your controller at the same time constitutes two or more requests, each will have their own DbContext. Configuring the DbContext as a Singleton for instance would be very bad, as *all* requests would be attempting to use the same Instance, Parallel operations need special consideration to scope a DbContext instance within the method call. Typically I would register and inject a Factory class to provide a DbContext in that case or a Unit of Work container.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK every web request runs with its own `DbContext` instance if you configure it like this.

However during request processing, multiple threads (or Tasks) may be created that each use that same instance, leading to this error.

This may be fixed by [enabling MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets) by adding **`;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`** to your connection string, with restrictions:

- Your **DB Provider** needs to support it. The SQL Server provider supports it, but certainly not all providers will do so.
- The concurring queries must all use **supported query statements**, e.g. 2 `SELECT`s can run at the same time, but a `SELECT` in parallel with an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` could (or will) fail, not to mention other types of commands such as `CREATE`.

Using MARS can slow down things a bit because of switching overhead, meaning that two parallel queries can take more time in total than doing them one after the other. But making sure that all threads or tasks in all requests synchronize their DB access so everything runs serially can be hard to accomplish. In my experience so far the slowdown has never been a problem, but your situation may be different.

Comment: Enabling MARS cannot fix the error in question - it is purely from EF Core simultaneous `DbContext` instance usage protection.