# Why the method does not return custom exception message

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I would like to an async method "UpdateAsync" return custom exception message when PutAsync method is invoked. What I do now is mock the class which  is PutAsync belong to, and then I setup the method and give the parameter. I also use Throws to custom exception message.

The problem is when I run this

```
var result = await this.repository.UpdateAsync(new EndPoint(new Uri(testUrl), HttpMethod.Put), JObject.FromObject(new object()), this.exceptionProcessor);
```

The PutAsync keep running without return exception. 
Here is the code.

```
Mock<RestClient> rc = new Mock<RestClient>();
rc.Setup(x => x.PutAsync(new Uri(testUrl), JObject.FromObject(new object()), new NameValueCollection()))
.Throws(new Exception("TestMessage"));

var result = await this.repository.UpdateAsync(new EndPoint(new Uri(testUrl), HttpMethod.Put), JObject.FromObject(new object()), this.exceptionProcessor);
Assert.IsTrue(result.ErrorMessages.GetValue(string.Empty).Equals("TestMessage"));
```

here is the main part of UpdateAsync, when process goes here, it will enter GetClient() first and then jump to Exception direct. This test was wrote using Shimes, but we don't want to use Shimes anymore, therefore I need to use another way to do.

```
public virtual async Task<GenericOperationResult<object>> UpdateAsync(EndPoint endpoint, JContainer obj, IExceptionProcessor exceptionProcessor, NameValueCollection headers){

     if (endpoint.ActionMethod == HttpMethod.Put)
     {
        result = await this.GetClient().PutAsync(endpoint.Url, obj, headers);
     }
     else if (endpoint.ActionMethod == HttpMethod.Post)
     {
        result = await this.GetClient().PostAsync(endpoint.Url, obj, headers);
     }
     else
     {
        throw new ConfigurationException("Update supports only POST or PUT verbs. Check endpoint configuration.");
     }
     return new GenericOperationResult<object>(200, result); 
}
```

Comment: when the setup expectation does not match what is actually passed to the mocked method then it wont behave as expected when invoked.

Comment: You probably want `.Returns(Task.FromException(new Exception("TestMessage")))` instead of `Throws`.

Comment: @Lee with the way you offer, it shows can not convert Tasks.Task to Linq.JObject

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating new objects in your setup, which are different from the objects you are instantiating in your call to UpdateAsync, so they won't match and the Mock object won't throw the exception. You could instead setup the mock to throw the exception if objects of the correct types are passed in, with the Url param also checking it has the testUrl, for example:

```
rc.Setup(x => x.PutAsync(It.Is<Uri>(u => u.OriginalString == testUrl), It.IsAny<JObject>(), It.IsAny<NameValueCollection>())
    .ThrowsAsync(new Exception("TestMessage"));
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. With your way is more making sense. however the process still not does not exception when PutAsync is invoke, this is PutAsync , public virtual Task<JObject> PutAsync(Uri uri, JContainer contentObject, NameValueCollection headers = null), should I change validation rule to make it be triggered?

Comment: Ah you should be using ThrowsAsync rather than Throws (code updated), although you will probably need to sure your PutAsync method is actually marked as async.

Comment: the PutAsync is a virtual method, public virtual Task<JObject> PutAsync(Uri uri, JContainer contentObject, NameValueCollection headers = null)

Comment: Can you change the virtual method signature to be async? (it is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015853/is-it-ok-to-have-virtual-async-method-on-base-class). Failing this perhaps you could provide all your code. It would be helpful to see the whole UpdateAsync method.

Comment: I updated my question, UpdateAsync is added , thanks for help

Comment: Currently the custom exception is not working, I also create another testing project and test a very simple method by this same way, the custom exception is also not working. very strange..

Comment: I can't see any code that actually injects the mocked object rc into your repository class. You are setting up a mock object but I can't see how you are using it?

Comment: See the answer to this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115928/unit-testing-with-dependency-injection-and-moq    Note in the test method how the mock is passed into the object tested in it's constructor.

Comment: the main class I test is RestClient, it is without interface, is it still possible to mock?